# Reduce the response of mongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53340d07d6429d27e1284c77"),
    "worktypes" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Pompas",
            "works" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "work 1",
                    "code" : "0001"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "Pompas "",
            "works" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "work 2",
                    "code" : "0002"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I did a query for get ONLY the works of one of worktype for this document, this is the query:

```
db.categories.find({$and: [
        { "_id": ObjectId('53340d07d6429d27e1284c77')},
        {"worktypes.name": "Pompas"}
    ]},{"worktypes.works.$":1})
```

But i got

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("53340d07d6429d27e1284c77"),
    "worktypes" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Pompas",
            "works" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "work 1",
                    "code" : "0001"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But i only need:

```
"works" : [ 
                    {
                        "name" : "work 1",
                        "code" : "0001"
                    }
                ]
```

How can i reduce this?

Comment: It's not possible to project a subset of an array.  You'll need to do it using map-reduce.  Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/mongodb-extract-only-the-selected-item-in-array)

Comment: Aggregation framework would be better here probably

Comment: So a correct usage of aggregate does get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator when working with arrays:

```js
db.catefories.aggregate([

    // Unwind the first array
    { "$unwind": "$worktypes" },

    // Then unwind the embedded array
    { "$unwind": "$worktypes.works" },

    // Match the item you want
    { "$match": {
        "worktypes.works.name": "work 1"
    }},

    // Group to reform the array structure
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "worktypes": { "$push": "$worktypes" }
    }}
])
```

And to get back as an array use [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) after the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/).

Answer (score 13):

I think [Neil Lunn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22690710/1438393) is mostly correct, but in my opinion it needs a few tweaks to get the expected result:

1. Match against `"worktypes.name"` rather than `"worktypes.works.name"`
2. In the `$group` phase, use `$first` instead of `$push` to get the first element alone
3. Add a `$project` phase to just get the `"works"`

```js
db.categories.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$worktypes" },
    { "$unwind": "$worktypes.works" },
    { "$match": {
        "worktypes.name": "Pompas"
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "works": { "$first": "$worktypes.works" }
    }},
    { "$project": {"_id":0, "works":1} }
])
```

**Output:**

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "works" : {
                                "name" : "work 1",
                                "code" : "0001"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can selectively remove fields from the projection like so:

```
db.categories.find({$and: [
    { "_id": ObjectId('53340d07d6429d27e1284c77')},
    {"worktypes.name": "Pompas"}
]},{"worktypes.works.$":1, _id:0 })
```

this will prevent the _id field from being projected.

Comment: With this dont return onlye the array, get other fields too, but thanks.